# Reporting Services 2008 - 401: Unauthorized

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, security, reporting-services

I've an application that connects to Reporting Services in SQL Server 2008 R2.

**The error is the following:**

```
System.Net.WebException: The request failed with HTTP status 401: Unauthorized.
at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse
   (SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, 
    Boolean asyncCall)
at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke
   (String methodName, Object[] parameters)
at Microsoft.SqlServer.ReportingServices2005.Execution.ReportExecutionService.LoadReport
   (String Report, String HistoryID)
```

**The application is running in production fine in 2 different customers**, so it's not a codeing issue.

I'm trying to install it now on a customer's server, which is using AD.  The SQL Server and the IIS is all in the same machine though, so I don't really care about AD.

It runs if I run IE as Administrator, but it doesn't work with other users.  The ASP.NET app is connecting to SSRS using a user created in the local machine (called *ReportingServicesUser*), member of the ReportingServicesUser group.

**Things I've tried:**

- Adding *ReportingServicesUser* to the Site Settings in the RS website (did the same for Network Service, IUSR, the Authenticated Users group, Local Service, etc)
- Adding *ReportingServicesUser* to the folder permissions in the RS website (did the same for Network Service, IUSR, the Authenticated Users group, Local Service, etc)
- Added permissions for that users to the databases (app database and RS related dbs)
- Added NTFS permissions to the RS folders (I will double check though).
- Connecting to the RS using `http://localhost`, `http://computername` and `http://domain.com`

For reference, the code is this (simplified version):

```
var service = new ReportExecutionService();
service.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("ReportingServicesUser", "password");
service.Url = "http://computername:90/ReportServer/ReportExecution2005.asmx";

service.ExecutionHeaderValue = new ExecutionHeader();

var execInfo = new ExecutionInfo();
execInfo = service.LoadReport("path-to-the-report", null);
===>  Here it throws the exception
```

I've read a lot of posts and pages about this but I cannot get an answer that works for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I've finally had to change the code to:

```
rs.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
```

and it worked.  Probably there's another solution but I couldn't find it out.

Comment: I would not say this is a solution because often you want the report server execution to under a different credential other than the current windows identity (which is what you are essentially doing).

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you gave "ReportingServicesUser" browse permissions for the specific report in ssrs? The request never made it to the server it seems but I would check \Reporting Services\LogFiles just to be certain.

Also, Your "report user" user needs to be defined on the reporting server with the credentials you send.

Comment: Yes, I've added the user in Site Settings and in the root folder settings with all the permissions, even Admin! I'll check the logs though.